# Jquery: Link text color to random background image

Tags: jquery, css, random

I'm using jQuery to randomly assign a background-image to my webpage every time the window is refreshed. I would like to assign a corresponding text-color to each background.

I'm trying with this code but having no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg'];

    $('body').css({
        'background-image': 'url(img/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'
    });

    if ($('body').css('background-image') === 'img/5.jpg') {
        $('#intro').css('color', 'red!important');
    };
});
```

Comment: Everytime the window is refreshed, everything is lost, you'll have to use localStorage or cookies.

Comment: Why not put the random number into a variable, and then use that variable in the if (rather than trying to retrieve the background image you previously assigned)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.css('background-image')` returns an image URL wrapped with `url()`. I would use an array of objects instead:

```
var themes = [{
    image: '1.jpg',
    color: 'red'
}, {
    image: '2.jpg',
    color: 'orange'
}];
```

Now, you can do:

```
var theme = themes[Math.floor(Math.random() * themes.length)];

$('body').css({
    'background-image': 'url("img/' + theme.image + '")',
    'color': theme.color
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not update your `images` array so that each element is actually an array of `background/text-color' - like this:

```
var images = [['1.jpg', '#000'], ['2.jpg', '#111'], ['3.jpg', '#222'], ['4.jpg', '#333'], ['5.jpg', '#444'], ['6.jpg', '#555']];
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]
$(body).css({
    'background-image': 'url(img/' + images[random][0] + ')',
    'color':            images[random][1]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting `console.log($('body').css('background-image'))` to see what is returning this. I think that is returning something like **url(img/5.jpg)** instead of **img/5.jpg**

also probably is easier if set the random thing into a variable and then do the compare with that variable instead of css attribute

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
var styles = [
    { image: '1.jpg', color: 'blue' },
    { image: '2.jpg', color: 'green' },
    ...
];

var style = styles[Math.floor(Math.random() * styles.length)];
$(body).css{ 'background-image': 'url(img/' + style.image + ')',
             'color': style.color + '!important' });
```

However, the basic problem with your code is that you're forgot `url(...)` when you compared to the existing style, it should be:

```
if ($('body').css('background-image') === 'url(img/5.jpg)') {
```